# Can not compile new flutter_2.0.4 with emulator of Genymotion (Samsung Galaxy S10)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, emulation, genymotion

When I was working with flutter 1.22.3 using Genymotion Emulators, everything worked fine. Then I decided to download the flutter 2.0.4. I launched the basic app created with "flutter create" on the Genymotion Samsung Galaxy S10 emulator. Unfortunately, I got the log below after the app crashed immediately after a splash screen:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Samsung Galaxy S10 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                      2,692ms
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
E/DartVM  ( 2619): version=2.12.2 (stable) (Wed Mar 17 10:30:20 2021 +0100) on "android_ia32"
E/DartVM  ( 2619): pid=2619, thread=2646, isolate_group=main(0xe44aa200), isolate=main(0xe44b4400)
E/DartVM  ( 2619): isolate_instructions=cca91300, vm_instructions=cca91300
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xccbc1b3b fp 0xcb28af38 /data/app/com.example.testproj-3zS27JWmImm1j3dkU2FARQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x1828b3b
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xcce52b51 fp 0xcb28af58 /data/app/com.example.testproj-3zS27JWmImm1j3dkU2FARQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x1ab9b51
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xcca91497 fp 0xcb28af88 /data/app/com.example.testproj-3zS27JWmImm1j3dkU2FARQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x16f8497
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xccad23d1 fp 0xcb28afd8 /data/app/com.example.testproj-3zS27JWmImm1j3dkU2FARQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x17393d1
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xccacf401 fp 0xcb28b0a8 /data/app/com.example.testproj-3zS27JWmImm1j3dkU2FARQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x1736401
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xccad00bd fp 0xcb28b168 /data/app/com.example.testproj-3zS27JWmImm1j3dkU2FARQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x17370bd
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xccae023d fp 0xcb28b228 /data/app/com.example.testproj-3zS27JWmImm1j3dkU2FARQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x174723d
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xccae0707 fp 0xcb28b2e8 /data/app/com.example.testproj-3zS27JWmImm1j3dkU2FARQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x1747707
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xcce392ae fp 0xcb28b368 /data/app/com.example.testproj-3zS27JWmImm1j3dkU2FARQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x1aa02ae
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xcce3960e fp 0xcb28b408 /data/app/com.example.testproj-3zS27JWmImm1j3dkU2FARQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x1aa060e
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xcc607558 fp 0xcb28b478 /data/app/com.example.testproj-3zS27JWmImm1j3dkU2FARQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x126e558
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xcc608353 fp 0xcb28b4b8 /data/app/com.example.testproj-3zS27JWmImm1j3dkU2FARQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x126f353
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xcc6068c5 fp 0xcb28b4e8 /data/app/com.example.testproj-3zS27JWmImm1j3dkU2FARQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x126d8c5
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xcc60437b fp 0xcb28b558 /data/app/com.example.testproj-3zS27JWmImm1j3dkU2FARQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x126b37b
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xcc603ce4 fp 0xcb28b768 /data/app/com.example.testproj-3zS27JWmImm1j3dkU2FARQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x126ace4
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xcc60339c fp 0xcb28b998 /data/app/com.example.testproj-3zS27JWmImm1j3dkU2FARQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x126a39c
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xcc60d07c fp 0xcb28bbb8 /data/app/com.example.testproj-3zS27JWmImm1j3dkU2FARQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x127407c
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xcc613e98 fp 0xcb28bce8 /data/app/com.example.testproj-3zS27JWmImm1j3dkU2FARQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x127ae98
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xcc623f51 fp 0xcb28bde8 /data/app/com.example.testproj-3zS27JWmImm1j3dkU2FARQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x128af51
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xcc5cc41c fp 0xcb28be08 /data/app/com.example.testproj-3zS27JWmImm1j3dkU2FARQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x123341c
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xcc5cf214 fp 0xcb28be98 /data/app/com.example.testproj-3zS27JWmImm1j3dkU2FARQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x1236214
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xcc5cf125 fp 0xcb28bec8 /data/app/com.example.testproj-3zS27JWmImm1j3dkU2FARQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x1236125
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xcc5d58fb fp 0xcb28bee8 /data/app/com.example.testproj-3zS27JWmImm1j3dkU2FARQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x123c8fb
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xcc5d5929 fp 0xcb28bf08 /data/app/com.example.testproj-3zS27JWmImm1j3dkU2FARQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x123c929
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xf48e1488 fp 0xcb28bf38 android::SimpleLooperCallback::handleEvent(int, int, void*)+0x28
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xf48e2415 fp 0xcb28c088 android::Looper::pollInner(int)+0x415
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xf48e1f4f fp 0xcb28c0c8 android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+0x3f
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xeb194781 fp 0xcb28c118 ALooper_pollOnce+0x61
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xcc5d583e fp 0xcb28c148 /data/app/com.example.testproj-3zS27JWmImm1j3dkU2FARQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x123c83e
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xcc5cf0d3 fp 0xcb28c168 /data/app/com.example.testproj-3zS27JWmImm1j3dkU2FARQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x12360d3
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xcc5cec03 fp 0xcb28c188 /data/app/com.example.testproj-3zS27JWmImm1j3dkU2FARQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x1235c03
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xcc5d2ce0 fp 0xcb28c1c8 /data/app/com.example.testproj-3zS27JWmImm1j3dkU2FARQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x1239ce0
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xf399eb06 fp 0xcb28c1e8 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so+0x11ab06
E/DartVM  ( 2619):   pc 0xf3933648 fp 0xcb28c218 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so+0xaf648
E/DartVM  ( 2619): -- End of DumpStackTrace
```

I can not figure out the reason of that crash. Any suggestions?

Edit:
I've dive deep into the issue and found that flutter does not support x86 architecture as Genymotion emulator has, BUT all apps have worked fine before 2.x.x flutter version on the emulators

Comment: try updating android studio & try flutter doctor to see if there is any problem

Comment: @UjjwalRaijada no effect